# Gridsplitter in a Grid with an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, wpftoolkit, itemscontrol

I'm trying to make a PropertyGrid Custom Control. The PropertyGrid will be very similar to the PropertyGrid used in Visual Studio. I've tried using the PropertyGrid of the Extended WPF Toolkit but you have to specify the category of a property with an attribute and we need to change the categories runtime. Which as far as I know is impossible with attributes.

So I'm making the PropertyGrid myself. This is my code so far:

The Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HomeMadePropertyGrid"
                    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="toggleButtonTemplate" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Grid Width="15" Height="13" Background="Transparent">
            <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}" Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1,1,1,1" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="toggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource toggleButtonTemplate}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PropertyGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PropertyGrid}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Background="{Binding GridColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PropertyGrid}}">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" Height="20" Width="20" Style="{StaticResource toggleButtonStyle}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Grid Visibility="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" 
                                                          Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">

                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{Binding GridColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PropertyGrid}}">
                                                            <TextBlock Background="White" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                                        </Border>
                                                        <GridSplitter Width="1" 
                                                                      Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="1" 
                                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                                      Background="{Binding GridColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PropertyGrid}}"/>
                                                        <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{Binding GridColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:PropertyGrid}}">
                                                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Value}">
                                                                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
                                                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}" 
                                                                             BorderThickness="0"/>
                                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Int32}">
                                                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}" 
                                                                             TextAlignment="Right"
                                                                             BorderThickness="0"/>
                                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Double}">
                                                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}" 
                                                                             TextAlignment="Right"
                                                                             BorderThickness="0"/>
                                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Boolean}">
                                                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}"
                                                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                                            </ContentPresenter>
                                                        </Border>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

PropertyGrid.cs

```
public class PropertyGrid : ItemsControl
{
    public Brush GridColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(GridColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GridColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GridColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(PropertyGrid), new UIPropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent)));

    static PropertyGrid()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(PropertyGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(PropertyGrid)));
    }
}
```

PropertyGroup

```
public class PropertyGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PropertyGridItem> Items { get; set; }

    public PropertyGroup()
    {
        Items = new List<PropertyGridItem>();
        Name = "";
    }
}
```

PropertyGridItem

```
public class PropertyGridItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public PropertyGridItem(string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        Name = propertyName;
        Value = propertyValue;
    }
}
```

This code in my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<local:PropertyGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}" GridColor="#f0f0f0"/>
```

Code behind of my ViewModel:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

The ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<PropertyGroup> Groups { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Groups = new List<PropertyGroup>();

        PropertyGroup group1 = new PropertyGroup();
        group1.Name = "Group1";
        group1.Items.Add(new PropertyGridItem("Item1", "test"));
        group1.Items.Add(new PropertyGridItem("Item2", 300));
        group1.Items.Add(new PropertyGridItem("Item3", true));
        group1.Items.Add(new PropertyGridItem("Item4", 5.2));
        Groups.Add(group1);

        PropertyGroup group2 = new PropertyGroup();
        group2.Name = "Group2";
        group2.Items.Add(new PropertyGridItem("Item1", "test"));
        group2.Items.Add(new PropertyGridItem("Item2", 300));
        group2.Items.Add(new PropertyGridItem("Item3", true));
        group2.Items.Add(new PropertyGridItem("Item4", 5.2));
        Groups.Add(group2);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the GridSplitter is applied every row. I want the GridSplitter to be applied to all rows of a group. I understand that this is because I make a new Grid for every item. For the attached properties to work the items have to be a direct child of the Grid. 
A DataGrid also isn't an option because the GridSplitter is only available between column headers.

So to make a long story short: how can I use a Grid in an ItemsControl with a GridSplitter that applies to all rows of ideally a group or the entire Grid if that isn't possible.

Comment: Its all I need! Can you share source of your code?

Comment: @twister0k What I've shared in the question and answers is pretty much all I can share. With this code you should be able to make a simple property grid. Is there a particular problem that I could help you solve?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made a simple project based on your code, but, I don't know why, it doesn't work. If you have a time, please, see the [code](https://github.com/twister0k/propertyGridwpf)

Comment: I corrected your code and uploaded it [here](https://github.com/Martijn-vd-H/SimplePropGrid). The code contains a working solution. The reason it didn't work was because you didn't make a custom control of the property grid.

Comment: It works. Thanks! But now, I have the same issue that you had before, the GridSplitter is applied to every row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this problem.

To get this to work I had to:

- Set the Grid.IsSharedSizeScope to true on the parent ItemsControl.
- Set the SharedSizeGroup property on the name column with an arbitrary name.
- Remove the star sizing on the name column. Having both the first and third column with star sizing resulted in a stuck GridSplitter for some reason.
- Set a fixed width on the GridSplitter, I set the Width to 2.
- Set the ResizeBehaviour of the GridSplitter to PreviousAndNext.

Here is a relevant piece of the resulting code:

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Visibility="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="nameColumn"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Column="0"  Style="{StaticResource BodyPropertyGrid_CellBorder}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </Border>
                <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="2"
                              ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                              Style="{StaticResource BodyPropertyGridSplitter}"/>
                <Border Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource BodyPropertyGrid_CellBorder}">
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" 
                                    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource propertyItemTemplateSelector}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you didn't provide us with a nice simple piece of code that only demonstrates your problem and I don't have time to get it to compile and run in my test project, so I can only give you suggestions and not tested solutions. Next time, please take the time to show a code example that we can just copy and paste into a project.

You might be able to get your 'stretched' `GridSplitter` if you join all of the row `Grid`s using the [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton, Path=IsChecked, Converter=
    {StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="FirstColumn" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="GridSplitterColumn" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" SharedSizeGroup="LastColumn" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortunately it didn't work. The GridSplitter cannot be moved anymore and the columns have an Auto width. Sorry for not adding test code before. I edited my question and added all the code needed to make a test project.