# Adding GridSplitter to dynamically created grid rows?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am developing a view which has a hierarchical select-able tree & `ItemsControl` bound to a collection of charts. These charts are resolved at run time depending on user selection. I want the charts to stretch vertically & share all available space.

I have used [Rachel Lim's class](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/) to dynamically resolve rows in a grid at run time using attached properties in an ItemsControl ItemsPanelTemplate. This works as expected and the charts share the available space

```
 <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"  
      x:Name="TimeSeriesCharting"                                                                                          
          ItemsSource="{Binding TimeSeriesChartViewModels}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Grid helpers:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
                                  helpers:GridHelpers.StarRows="0,1,2,3">
                            </Grid>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}"/>
             </Style>
         </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>                        
 </ItemsControl>
```

I now want to add a `GridSplitter` into every row of said grid. In the grid helpers class when row definitions are added I try to add a `GridSplitter` however when trying to manipulate the `grid.Children` collection it throws an InvalidOperationException - *Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel.*

```
   public static void RowCountChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (!(obj is Grid) || (int)e.NewValue < 0)
      {
        return;
      }

      Grid grid = (Grid)obj;
      grid.RowDefinitions.Clear();

      for (int i = 0; i < (int)e.NewValue; i++)
       {
         grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
          {
            Height = GridLength.Auto
          });

          SetStarRows(grid);
         }

            grid.Children.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < grid.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
            {
                GridSplitter gridSplitter = new GridSplitter();
                gridSplitter.SetResourceReference(FrameworkElement.StyleProperty, "HorizontalGridSplitterStyle");
                Grid.SetRow(gridSplitter, i);
                grid.Children.Add(gridSplitter);
            }        
        }
```

I'm assuming there is an issue using an `ItemsControl` in this situation. Is there a better pattern to follow here? Write the custom grid as a stand alone user control maybe?

Comment: You could try to put the GridSplitter in the ItemTemplate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491585/gridsplitter-in-a-grid-with-an-itemscontrol

Comment: I can't explicitly set the Grid.Row property on the item because I don't resolve the rows until run time. I've tried to put the GridSplitter in the item itself which is a view. This works for that view but obviously is dumb to all other views so they do not resize...

Comment: Here's an existing answer that hints at a possible direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22833717/2706. I am exploring this, too.